# Get attribute from model of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, select-options

I have an employee dropdown that lists all the employees. I want to be able to select an employee and get the address of the employee from the model so that I may display it. the following is the code of my collection_select.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2 field">
<%= form.label :employee_id %>
<%= form.collection_select :employee_id, Employee.all, :id, :full_name,{:prompt=>"Select Employee"},{:id=>"emp_select",class:"form-control",:onchange=>"getEmployee();"} %>
</div>
```

Next is the code I am using to grab the value of the employee that was selected and it does work.

```
function getEmployee() {
    var selectedVal=$('#emp_select option:selected').val();}
```

From here what do I do to get the address of the employee that was selected?

Comment: Where do you want to display an address? Is address an attribute of Employee model or a separate model?

Comment: The address is an attribute in the employee. Each employee has a different address. I want to display the address in the form schedule form that the dropdown is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add address to option data-attribute:

```
<%= form.select :employee_id, 
  options_for_select(Employee.all.map { 
    |e| [e. full_name, e.id, { 'data-address' => e.address  }] 
  }), 
  { prompt: "Select Employee" }, 
  { id: "emp_select", class: "form-control", onchange: "getEmployee();" } %>
```

On change get it with js:

```
function getEmployee() {
  var selectedVal=$('#emp_select option:selected').data("address");}
```

And insert it to needed place

Comment: I am using the code you provided and I am not getting the address. The result I am getting is undefined. Any thoughts on what is missing.

Comment: Do you have a needed address string in `data-address` attribute for every select option? You can check it with html inspector/

Comment: your method worked. I have another question for you now. If I wanted to create a new definition called full_address that includes city, state, and zip and use that instead of address in the code you gave me, how would I do that?

Comment: @Jovany, happy to hear it!. Just create `full_address` method in your Employee model and replace `{ 'data-address' => e.address  }` with `{ 'data-address' => e.full_address  }`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I struggled with this for weeks. Awesome

Answer (score 1):

You will have to retrieve the employee's address via `ajax` call. Here are the steps:

1. Define an action in your rails app to return employee's address by `json`.
2. Make an ajax request to that action and get the info needed.
3. Render result into view.

For more information, take a look at this link:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

**routes.rb**

```
controller :ajax do
  get 'ajax/get_employee_address/:employee_id', action: :get_employee_address, as: :get_employee_address
end
```

**ajax_controller.rb**

```
class AjaxController < ActionController::Base
  def get_employee_address
    employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])

    render json: employee.address.to_json
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render json: 'Employee not found', status: 422
  end
end
```

**Your js code**

```
function getEmployee() {
  var selectedVal=$('#emp_select option:selected').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/get_employee_address/' + selectedVal,
    success: function (address) {
      // Render your address to view
    },
    error: function () {
      // Handle error here or just return nothing
      return null;
    }
  })
}
```

**Note**: This ajax endpoint will expose your employee address to outside so be sure to make authentication to prevent leaking info.

Comment: Well, not exactly "have to". Since OP's getting all the employees' ids and names, he might as well render their addresses somewhere in HTML and just retrieve that with JS.

Comment: I have no experience with Ajax. Just took a look at it. Seems like it would take a while for me to learn it all. Would you be able to help more?

Comment: Yes, it could be that case. I was choosing this approach since the OP said he wanted to retrieve from the model.

Comment: @Jovany Sure, I will post an updated answer to clarify my idea soon.

Comment: What do you mean Marcin about rendering the addresses in HTML? I dont want all the addresses just the one for the employee selected.

Comment: @HDox what was your idea to accomplish this

Comment: To do this method I have to create an Ajax controller? Or should rails already have it in the app?

Comment: @Jovany You will have to do on your own.

Comment: I was able to apply the ajax to a variable. When I display the variable I get object Object. I am not getting any errors or console input. Any thought on the issue?